# creating an if statement to pull same text within a folder

Tags: python

I am trying to search for files in a folder path containing a certain date. The date is formatted as `YearMonthDay`. My current string is:

```
mydate = datetime.date(2015,10,05)
print(mydate.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

This will give me my desired output of `20151005`.

Next, I am trying to create an if statement that says, `if date = '20151005'` pull all files from path.

Any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: is `if mydate.strftime('%Y%m%d') == '20151005'` what you are looking for...?

Comment: From what path?  Do you have a subdirectory of the current working directory called `20151005`?  What does "pull all files" mean?

Comment: @RNar -- You need `==`, you can't do an assignment in an `if` statement.

Comment: sorry yeah, that's what I meant, editted

Comment: it's unclear whether you want to pull only the files that contain the given date or all of them if any one of them does

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in glob.glob('*.h'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if mydate.strftime('%Y%m%d') in contents:
        print file
```

Comment: hopefully the file will be small enough to fit in memory